# How do I reset choc-ui chakra-autocomplete when using react hook form

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

I made this autocomplete component using [choc ui autocomplete](https://github.com/anubra266/choc-autocomplete). I create forms using react hook form and after submitting call the reset method. The rest of my form fields will clear but the autocomplete ui stays populated even if the internal value is empty. Not only is that bad, the user also has to toggle values to set it again.

[image]

I decided that maybe I need to pass value to the AutoComplete component but that didn't work. (Given react hook form, I use useWatch to get the value for plan, so dont worry about no rendering being an issue, the value does get passed)

```
import { Icon, InputGroup, InputRightElement } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import {
  AutoComplete,
  AutoCompleteInput,
  AutoCompleteItem,
  AutoCompleteList,
} from "@choc-ui/chakra-autocomplete";
import { FiChevronDown, FiChevronRight } from "react-icons/fi";

interface Props {
  onChange: (arg0: string) => void;
  list: { [key: string | number]: any }[];
  labelKey: string;
  valueKey: string;
  value?: string;
  placeholder: string;
}

const Autocomplete = ({
  onChange,
  list,
  labelKey: label,
  valueKey,
  value,
  placeholder,
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <AutoComplete openOnFocus onChange={onChange} value={value}>
      {({ isOpen }: { isOpen: boolean }) => (
        <>
          <InputGroup>
            <AutoCompleteInput
              placeholder={placeholder}
              type="text"
              errorBorderColor="red.300"
            />
            <InputRightElement
              children={<Icon as={isOpen ? FiChevronRight : FiChevronDown} />}
            />
          </InputGroup>
          <AutoCompleteList>
            {list.map((_list, cid) => (
              <AutoCompleteItem
                key={`option-${cid}`}
                label={_list[label]}
                value={_list[valueKey]}
                textTransform="capitalize"
              >
                {_list[label]}
              </AutoCompleteItem>
            ))}
          </AutoCompleteList>
        </>
      )}
    </AutoComplete>
  );
};

export default Autocomplete;
```

Usage

```
        <GridItem rowSpan={1} colSpan={1}>
          <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors.startingDate}>
            <FormLabel>Starting Date</FormLabel>
            <Input
              {...register("startingDate")}
              type="date"
              errorBorderColor="red.300"
            />
            {errors.startingDate && (
              <FormErrorMessage>{errors.startingDate.message}</FormErrorMessage>
            )}
          </FormControl>
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem rowSpan={1} colSpan={1}>
          <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors.plan}>
            <FormLabel>Plan</FormLabel>
            <Autocomplete
              placeholder="Plan"
              labelKey="plan"
              valueKey="_id"
              list={plan}
              value={getValues("plan")}
              onChange={(val) => setValue("plan", val)}
            />
            {errors.plan && (
              <FormErrorMessage>{errors.plan.message}</FormErrorMessage>
            )}
          </FormControl>
        </GridItem>
```

I tried passing register from react hook form to the AutoCompleteInput as well but that didn't work either.

How do I reset my AutoComplete?

Comment: use `Controller` component from `react-hook-form` and put the `Autocomplete` inside it's `render` prop.